# Why can't I get my LCD1602 with a HD44780 controller using I2C with Windows IoT to work?

Tags: pi-2, i2c, windows-iot

I have tried about every example available on the internet.  Probably spent hours attempting to get this LCD1602 to function properly.

I can never get anything to display on the LCD.  It just remains brightly lit as it was when I initially plugged it into my Raspberry pi 2...  What changes do I need to make to get my device to work properly with the library below?

The library I ended up using [this](https://github.com/DzeryCZ/Character-LCD-over-I2C):

- Character-LCD-over-I2C
- ===================
- Connect HD44780 LCD character display to Windows 10 IoT devices via I2C and PCF8574
  *
- Author: Jaroslav Zivny
- Version: 1.1
- Keywords: Windows IoT, LCD, HD44780, PCF8574, I2C bus, Raspberry Pi 2
- Git: https://github.com/DzeryCZ/Character-LCD-over-I2C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was talking to somebody at work about this project and he told me that he had the exact same LCD and was using it with an arduino.  He also mentioned how he had trouble with it always displaying bright blue and never showing text until he adjusted the contrast on the device to dim the display a bit.

I gave it a try on my device and YAY !!!  It is now working.

So, the solution to my problem was as follows:

1. Run the program that is supposed to be writing text tot he LCD1602.
2. On the HD44780 board that is mounted to the back of your LCD1602, locate the square blue potentiometer.
3. Turn the little screw in the middle of the potentiometer back and forth a bit until you see the letters showing up.
4. Jump up and down and do a HAPPY DANCE !!!  IT WORKS !!!